# How to use django-discussion application?

Tags: django

I recently learned about [django-discussion](https://github.com/incuna/django-discussion). I don't know it may be a great application but I couldn't find any documentation, no example anywhere on the web.

Can somebody please guide me to the right direction? How can I integrate it with other application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the lists of django forum applications [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ForumAppsComparison) and [here](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/forums/), there are better alternatives like [django-threadedcomments](https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments), [djangobb](https://bitbucket.org/slav0nic/djangobb) or [pybbm](https://github.com/hovel/pybbm) - take a look.

Plus, `django-discussion` is not actively developed now.

Hope that helps.